# LoadRunner why is URL mode solving all my issues with Javas

Tags: javascript, loadrunner

First I recorded a script against my "Rich" Internett Application having Wickets and JavaScripts and it did not go very well at replay. 
However, recording in URL mode solved a lot of these issues. 
Why is that? 
In general I assume that my script recorded in URL mode did capture things like:

```
web_url("bootstrap-collapse-ver-12312478469.js" 
.
.
.
"RecContentType=text/JavaScript",
```

and these calls to i.e. JavaScript manipulating the web page made the page recognizabel the the replay because the Javascripts where actually executed during replay. In HTML mode these Javascripts where not executed (not seing them in my script after recording), and hence the page did not have the proper state for the replay to recognize it?

Is my assumption correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only client types which execute JavaScript are

- GUI Virtual users (QTP Operating Against Full Browsers)
- Citrix|RDP operating against full browsers
- TruClient

What you are seeing is the output of the executed JavaScript as a set of explicit requests.

Comment: Ok, but then what are the rationale to use URL mode instead of HTML mode? (Accepts that the script gets less readable :-)

Comment: "What you are seeing is the output of the executed JavaScript as a set of explicit requests".
So if I can seee the output, then the JavaScript is executed?

Comment: There is also a lot of web_url calls to .png files and css With typically "RecContentType=image/png". Which is not happening in the HTML mode?

Comment: When not in URL mode the base page is loaded into memory and processed.  Embedded resource calls on the page are referenced and loaded.  Often you will see then listed as EXTRARES (Extra Resources) on the page call.   Unless you need to correlate the request these items can be removed as the page parsing will reload the references anyway.

Comment: I prefer to work in URL Mode due to the lighter weight of each virtual user and having available each request explicitly to examine and modify if needed.   Javascript is executed in the browser as part of the page load.   As standard transport virtual users only make the requests without running a full browser client any JavaScript would necessarily not be executed (by Design).   You have other virtual user types (GUI/truClient) if you require to execute JavaScript.   For me, I just convert the JavaScript function I need to C and be done with it.